# npm run dev failed, to create the bundle.js file. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack-4

My webpack.config.js file code is:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
entry: './src/js/index.js',
output: {
path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
filename: 'bundle.js'
},
 mode: 'development'
};
```

package.json file:

```
  "name": "forkify",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "forkify project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "Parichay Pari",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.42.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

The error I'm getting is:
Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! forkify@1.0.0 dev: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the forkify@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/parichay/.npm/_logs/2020-03-08T05_08_19_681Z-debug.log

Comment: Did you try looking at the complete log like the error suggested? If so, what did that say?

Comment: Shaun E. Tobias how to look into the error log file?

Comment: `vi /home/parichay/.npm/_logs/2020-03-08T05_08_19_681Z-debug.log`

Comment: Di I need to run:
 vi /home/parichay/.npm/_logs/2020-03-08T05_08_19_681Z-debug.log

Comment: I did run it, got nothing.
Found a swap file by the name "~/.npm/_logs/.2020-03-08T05_08_19_681Z-debug.log.swp"(1) Another program may be editing the same file.  If this is the case,
    be careful not to end up with two different instances of the same
    file when making changes.  Quit, or continue with caution.
(2) An edit session for this file crashed.
  use ":recover" or "vim -r /home/parichay/.npm/_logs/2020-03-08T05_08_19_68
1Z-debug.log"
If you did this already, delete the swap file "/home/parichay/.npm/_logs/.2020-03-08T05_08_19_6
81Z-debug.log.swp"